# The each() function is deprecated; can't figure out how to change to foreach

Tags: php, each, deprecated

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // error reporting

// save uploaded files
$i = 1;
while (list ($item, $value) = each ($_FILES)){
    if(substr($item, 0, 11) == 'imageloader'){
        $fileName = $i.'.'.substr($item, 11, 3); // make file name
        move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $fileName); // save file
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

I need to use foreach. I have tried but it just doesn't work. Can anyone help me change the `EACH` to a `FOREACH` loop?

Comment: `foreach ($_FILES as $yourvar){
   blahblah with $yourvar
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `while (list ($item, $value) = each ($_FILES)){`

to

```
foreach( $_FILES as $key => $file ) { }
```

the syntax above is really old and shouldn't be used.

Moreover you don't get extension properly in order to get extension use

```
$ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

these are [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

in your case it would be:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // error reporting

// save uploaded files
$i = 1;
foreach ($_FILES as $item => $value)){
    if(substr($item, 0, 11) == 'imageloader'){
        $fileName = $i.'.'.substr($item, 11, 3); // make file name
        move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $fileName); // save file
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```